# what is pass by value and pass by reference?

Tags: c, function

I recently started learning c . Now i face some problem in function . I don't understand what is main difference between pass by value and pass by reference in function . Can anyone help me to figure out this problem with some code using c.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/430958/9038475) could help you.

Comment: TL;DR pass by value is when you copy the entire thing directly into function stack frame and pass by reference is when you copy only the reference of the entire thing into function stack frame which can then be used to reference the actual data in memory without copying it. That answer is 30 different things and could be rewritten as what I just said without all the bogus hurr durr confusion etc, nobody cares about what other people are confused about, I just need definition, it's not accepted, despite having 900+ upvotes for a reason, the asker doesn't like history either.